# DOMDocument::loadHTML() Source must not be empty error when inputting result from curl_multi_getcontent()

Tags: php-curl, querypath

Using `curl_multi_init` and querypath in a php environment, I am querying multiple websites and then reading the query results which should all be all HTML format. I process the results by using `curl_multi_getcontent()`. When using the results as input for Querypath to manually parse the results, I get this error:

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty ...
```

This is my code:

```
[... running in a loop for every request]    
$results = curl_multi_getcontent ($curl_arr[$i]);
$htmlString = (string) $results; //casting the result to string
        
//echo $htmlString;         //gives me the correct html result!
//echo strlen($htmlString); //proves that string is not empty!?
        
$qp = QueryPath::withHTML($htmlString); //this line is causing the error
```

I don't know what I might be missing. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I ran into an encoding problem. It worked once I changed `$htmlString = (string) $results;` into `$htmlString = utf8_decode($results);`